# How do I prevent programatically generated buttons from center aligning in Android?

Tags: android, button, alignment

I have a set of buttons that generate based on the number of items pulled from the SQLite database. The buttons generate and work fine but they center align and evenly space themselves out. Meaning if there is one: the button is centered; If there is two: they space evenly from the center; etc.

What I need is for them to stay left align and allow me to use margins to space them out. I know how to set the margins using the parameters but can't figure out why they are defaulting centered in the TableLayout row.

Again the code works and responds perfectly aside from the alignment. I've having similar issues on other activities and I'm sure it's related.

I've included some code that may show what I'm doing:

```
imgTitleTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagesTableLayout);

int i = 0;
while (i < imgTitle.length) {
    if (i % 6 == 0) {
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imgTitleTable.addView(tr);
        imgtr = new TableRow(this);
        imgtr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imgTitleTable.addView(imgtr);
    }
    // add images
    ImageButton imgButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_sample);
    imgButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    imgButton.setBackground(null);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Viewer.class);
            startActivity(theIntent);
        }
    });
    // add img title
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText(imgTitle[i]);
    title.setId(i);
    title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setWidth(imgButton.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
    title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Viewer.class);
            startActivity(theIntent);
        }
    });
    tr.addView(imgButton);
    imgtr.addView(title);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
params.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
imgButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: .setGravity() is reserved for a Layout. It's causing an error since imgButton is a type of ImageButton.

Comment: sorry about that, I have edited my answer. I'm not too familiar with table layouts but I think that should work